# docker-compose running 2 services with dockerfiles, The task "phx.server" could not be found, main.go: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, dockerfile, apache-phoenix

I have an issue running my docker-compose.yml file with 4 services. They are my go microservice, phoenix web server, mongodb and redis images.

I specified in both my phoenix and golang dockerfiles to change working directory before running both services. I currently get the following errors when I do docker-compose up.

The task "phx.server" could not be found
main.go: no such file or directory

Here is my Dockerfile.go.development:

```js
# base image elixer to start with
FROM golang:latest

# create app folder
RUN mkdir /goApp
COPY ./genesys-api /goApp
WORKDIR /goApp/cmd/genesys-server

# install dependencies
RUN go get gopkg.in/redis.v2
RUN go get github.com/gorilla/handlers
RUN go get github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go
RUN go get github.com/gorilla/context
RUN go get github.com/gorilla/mux
RUN go get gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson
RUN go get github.com/graphql-go/graphql

# run phoenix in *dev* mode on port 8080
CMD go run main.go
```

Here is my Dockerfile.phoenix.development:

```js
# base image elixer to start with
FROM elixir:1.6

# install hex package manager
RUN mix local.hex --force
RUN mix local.rebar --force

# install the latest phoenix 
RUN mix archive.install https://github.com/phoenixframework/archives/raw/master/phx_new.ez --force

# create app folder
RUN mkdir /app
COPY ./my_app /app
WORKDIR /app

# install dependencies
RUN mix deps.get

# run phoenix in *dev* mode on port 4000
CMD mix phx.server
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```js
version: '3.6'
services:
  go:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.go.development
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - .:/goApp
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
  phoenix:
    # tell docker-compose which Dockerfile it needs to build
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.phoenix.development
    # map the port of phoenix to the local dev port
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    # mount the code folder inside the running container for easy development
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    # make sure we start mongodb when we start this service
    # links:
    #   - db
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    environment:
      GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID: ${GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}
      GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET: ${GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET}
      FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID: ${FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID}
      FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET: ${FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET}
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ./data/redis:/data/redis
    entrypoint: redis-server
    restart: always
```

Comment: My instinct on seeing that error message and that Dockerfile is that `main.go` isn't getting copied in, or perhaps the directory structure isn't what you expect.  If you `RUN ls` in the Dockerfile, does the right thing come out?  (Or `docker run` based one one of the container IDs that gets printed out in the `docker build` output?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the error related to go microservice, Since the go binary is not found in PATH, you may need to set the GOPATH env variable via your docker file for go:

```
export GOPATH=
```